# zend framework - use 'Alnum' filter but retain commas

Tags: php, zend-framework

is there a way i can use the `Alnum` filter for a `Zend_Form_Element_Text` form element but still retain commas ? The input will be command seperated tags for an item. 
Do i have to define my own filter ? Is there a way to achieve this using the 'Callback' filter type ?

Expected input is `tag1,tag2,tag3`

```
$tags=new Zend_Form_Element_Text('tags');
$tags->setLabel('Tags:');
$tags->addFilters(array('Alnum','StripTags','StringTrim','HtmlEntities'));
```

---

**Update 1:**

the Zend_Filter_Alnum  has an option to allow whitespace which can be activated by

```
$tags->addFilters(array('StripTags','StringTrim','HtmlEntities',new Zend_Filter_Alnum(true)));
```

So the expected input will be `tag1 tag2 tag3` but still if anybody could suggest me a way to make it accept `tag1,tag2,tag3`, it would be awesome.

Comment: Extend Zend_Filter_Interface and make you're own custom filter , it should take you 10 min tops if you have a look at Zend_Filter_Alnum first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example , it shouldn't be used as is in a production environment :

```
class My_Filter_AlnumComma implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    public $allowComma;

    public function __construct($allowComma = false)
    {
        // have a look at a proper filter construct 
        // and change me
        $this->allowComma = (boolean) $allowComma;
    }

    public function getAllowComma()
    {
        return $this->allowComma;
    }

    public function setAllowComma($allowComma)
    {
        $this->allowComma = (boolean) $allowComma;
        return $this;
    }

    public function filter($value)
    {
        $comma = $this->allowComma ? ',' : '';
        $pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9' . $comma . ']/';        

        return preg_replace($pattern, '', (string) $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right approach though I would take a look at Zend_Filter_Alnum (http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Filter/Alnum.php) and copy that rather than the above as the ZF class has support for unicode and actual alphabets rather than just A-Z.

Comment: @David Caunt: i know , but this is just an example , if you look up a bit i've comented on the question and told him to look at Zend_Filter_Alnum first to see exactly how it should be done .